# Nexmo Verify SDK for Android

Tags: android, sms, vonage, sms-verification

I'm using Nexmo Verify SDK to verify the phone number of the user. I am able to get the pin to the given phone number but when i enter the correct pin code and call checkPinCode method i get INVALID_CREDENTIALS error. This is the implementation.

```
//This is how i collected the phone number 
final String phone = phoneNumber.getText().toString();
verifyClient.getVerifiedUser("LK",phone );
//This is how i collected the pin number
final String pin = pinNumberEditText.getText().toString();
verifyClient.checkPinCode(pin);
verifyClient.addVerifyListener(new VerifyClientListener() {
        @Override
        public void onVerifyInProgress(VerifyClient verifyClient, UserObject user) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Verifying", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onUserVerified(VerifyClient verifyClient, UserObject user) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Successfully Verified", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(VerifyClient verifyClient, com.nexmo.sdk.verify.event.VerifyError errorCode, UserObject user) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error"+errorCode+user.getPhoneNumber(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onException(IOException exception) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Exception", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
```

Help much appreciated.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Tested it out & looks like entering the correct pin results in a verified user but the 'onError' method is still invoked for some reason. This isn't altering the verification workflow, rather it is an extraneous Log statement. I have made a bug for this but you should be able to verify users with no issues.

CHECK raw response: Signature: . Content: {
                     "result_code": 0,
                     "result_message": "OK",
                     "timestamp": "1485034200",
                     "user_status": "verified",
                     "phone_number": ""
                 }

Comment: Yeah i also get the same message hope that thr will be a fix

Comment: Has been fixed!